# twitter search API per user

Tags: json, api, twitter, httpwebrequest

I am able to do the following,

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
    data:{
        q:'from:user1 OR from:user2',
        rpp:1,
        page:1,
        include_entities:1
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success:function (r){
        console.log(r)
    },
    error:function (){

    }
});
```

I need to get x number of tweets per user...

so for example the first two tweets of user_1, then the second two tweets from user_2 so I get 4 in total... or 6 if 3 users and so on... atm it's showing me a paginated option, and I don't wish to make multiple requests for each user as they are about 10 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went ahead and made a simple Yahoo Pipe for this. Could probably edit it to make it more robust but it combines 2 calls into one.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=15754ad56809f1970a5c7f5ac117f064

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://pipes.yahooapis.com/pipes/pipe.run',
    data:{
        Name1:'twitter',
        Name2:'twitterapi',
        id:'15754ad56809f1970a5c7f5ac117f064',
        render:'json'
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function (r){
        console.log(r)
    },
    error:function (){

        }
    });
```

Comment: am I able to do more than 2 users as I need about 7 :(

Comment: does that make 7 requests? if so then it is not useful for me as I can just do that manually myself, im trying to avoid the 150 requests per hour limit of twitter

Comment: no it doesn't make 7. it makes one request to the yahoo pipes api. Besides if your worried about the 150 request limit, you shouldn't be. Your using javascript to call the api. Each user will have 150 requests.